# Rails: control file store cache size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, caching

The documentation for the file-based cache in rails says:

> Note that the cache will grow until the disk is full unless you
>   periodically clear out old entries.

Unfortunately it doesnt give any information about how to clear old entries periodically. Does setting an appropriate value for `:expires_in` do the job or is there some other sort of black magic behind clearing the cache?

Also, the documenation gives an option to limit the memory-based cache in size:

```
config.cache_store = :memory_store, { size: 64.megabytes }
```

Does this also work for the file based cache? And even more importantly, what happens when the cache growths below that size limit? Does it remove old cached values or will it throw some kind of exception?

thanks in advance,
danijoo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Yes* the limit applies in case of file-based cache too. And *yes* a value for `:expires_in` will do the job.

When this limit is reached, no further stuff will be cached. No exception is thrown.

Answer (score 6):

Experimenting with FileStore cache I found that `:expires_in` options works, but `:size` one doesn't.

If you want to specify options then you need to also specify the path, try with the following example:

> config.cache_store = :file_store, Rails.root.join('tmp', 'cache'), { expires_in: 1.minute }

Put the code in `config/application.rb` and remember to activate the cache in `config/environments/development.rb` and restart the app.

P.S. I use 1 minute to easily do a quick test.

Answer (score 0):

The `size` option works for `MemoryStore` cache, but not for `FileStore` cache. Examining the source code of the `FileStore`, you will observe that [FileStore](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6b93fff8af32ef5e91f4ec3cfffb081d0553faf0/activesupport/lib/active_support/cache/file_store.rb) does not support the `size` option, unlike the [MemoryStore](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/bf725a787609cf24ae64d763636513fc0bfdd4bf/activesupport/lib/active_support/cache/memory_store.rb#L80).

`FileStore` cache entries will expire (be deleted) and be recreated when they are read, but nothing is deleting unused expired entries explicitly, so the cache will grow infinitely. If you want to periodically [cleanup](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/MemoryStore.html#method-i-cleanup) your expired entries you can run `Rails.cache.cleanup` explicitly.