# How do I properly manage the rails tmp directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

After I deploy a rails application in production mode, do I need to schedule a periodic cleanup of the rails tmp directory? aka: rake tmp:clear (or its sub-parts tmp:sessions:clear, tmp:cache:clear, tmp:sockets:clear).

I know a few major revisions of rails back this was something that was needed to be done. I'm currently using Rails 4.1.x. Thanks.

Comment: If an app leaves files behind in the tmp folder, I would investigate why that happens and not just delete them.

Comment: In case someone arrives here wondering if they can delete the tmp directory, the answer's ["yes"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16989297/5783745)

Comment: `rails tmp:clear` didn't do it for me, i really had to do `mv tmp/ tmp.b` (in the project folder, `rm` would have worked too) and then did `rails tmp:create`. The next start took long obv., but it worked for me.

Answer (score 12):

Add one or more of those to your crontab file and that should do it for
you...

```
rake tmp:cache:clear              
rake tmp:clear                     
rake tmp:create                     
rake tmp:sessions:clear              
rake tmp:sockets:clear
```

Keep in mind, clearing sessions will kill all active sessions to. I
don't recommend that. 
You could create a model called:

Periodic with something like this in it:

```
def self.run
      CGI::Session::ActiveRecordStore::Session.
        destroy_all( ['updated_at <?', 48.hours.ago] )
  end
```

then cron your script/runner like this

```
script/runner -e production Periodic.run
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's what **Rails 6** spits out for `rails --tasks` in terms of clearing the tmp directory.

```
rails tmp:clear     # Clear cache, socket and screenshot files from tmp/ (narrow w/ tmp:cache:clear, tmp:sockets:clear, tmp:screenshots:clear)
rails tmp:create    # Creates tmp directories for cache, sockets, and pids
```

**Note**: it does mention `tmp:cache:clear`, `tmp:sockets:clear`, `tmp:screenshots:clear` in the `tmp:clear` comment.

For me my cache was filling up my Docker container and running out of inodes, thus looking like it ran out of disk space. I'm going to try and configure caching settings for production to help this out.

It sounds like if you would like to have it auto expire with file caching you can do something like this: [Rails: control file store cache size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22333748/rails-control-file-store-cache-size).
They mention to use the `:expires_in` for file caches, otherwise you can set a memory size limit with something like `config.cache_store = :memory_store, { size: 64.megabytes }`

Also here's the current documentation on caching, which also mentions `:expires_in`

- https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html